# Angular property underfined when validating with ng-minlength

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular1.6

In my angular controller I try to verify that the user inserted 5 characters, and if there are less than 5 characters a warning should be displayed. My controller:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('FeedController', function ($scope, $http) {


    $scope.customPostText = "";
    $scope.sendMessage = function()
    {
        console.log("text ");
        console.log($scope.customPostText);
        var length = $scope.customPostText.length
        //could us:
        //if ($scope.postcommentForm.customPostText.$valid) instead to check if valid
        //but I want to see the length.
        if(length >4 && length < 255)
        {
                    alert("not undefined");
        }
        else
        {
            alert("message needs 5 characters you have."+length);
        }
    }
});
```

For some reason if I type less than 5 characters $scope.customPostText becomes undefined and an error in the log is written:

> Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

However on 5 characters or more there is no problem, I found out it's because I use ng-minlength in my html:

```
<div ng-controller="FeedController">
    <div class="row">
      <form id="postcommentForm" name="postcommentForm">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group" id="post-comment-textarea">
            <textarea class="form-control"  name="customPostText"  id="customPostText" maxlength="255"
                      ng-model="customPostText"
                      ng-minlength="5"  
                      ng-maxlength="255" 
                      ng-trim="true"
                      ng-class="{ 'success-border': postcommentForm.customPostText.$valid ,'error-border': !postcommentForm.customPostText.$valid }"   
                      ng-required="true"                              
                      ></textarea>
            <span class="input-group-addon  btn btn-success" 
                  ng-disabled="{{postcommentForm.customPostText.$valid == false}}" 
                  ng-click="sendMessage()"
                  ng-class="{ 'success-border': postcommentForm.customPostText.$valid ,'error-border': !postcommentForm.customPostText.$valid }"   >
              Send
            </span>

          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hstppbj8/46/)

However I need the ng-minlength for the validation I use in the ng-class:

```
ng-class="{ 'success-border': postcommentForm.customPostText.$valid ,'error-border': !postcommentForm.customPostText.$valid }"
```

How can I use ng-minlength without having the problem of the value being undefined?

Answer (score 0):

The min-length validation prevents the content to be sent when it is not valid.
Thus you only get undefined.

One way to handle this would be:

`var length = angular.isDefined($scope.customPostText) ? $scope.customPostText.length : 0`

This way you will get 0 as long as no valid input is writtin in the input field.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the issue is because of the ng-minlength you are using, it assigns the value to the ng-model only if it surpasses the min length. I don't think you can change this behavior

Not ideal but make shift solution is to remove min length and  what you can do is make a toggler kind of variable in the controller like

```
if(length >4 && length < 255)
    {
         $scope.length_valid = true; 
         alert("not undefined");
    }
    else
    {
         $scope.length_valid = false; 
         alert("message needs 5 characters.");
    }
```

And then in html

```
ng-class="{ 'success-border': postcommentForm.customPostText.$valid && length_valid ,'error-border': !postcommentForm.customPostText.$valid || !length_valid }"
```

Answer (score 0):

assign your variable with form name like this: **$scope.postcommentForm.customPostText** in your js

it will never give you undefined.

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ui.bootstrap']);


app.controller('FeedController', function ($scope, $http) {


$scope.customPostText = "";
$scope.sendMessage = function()
{
    console.log("text ");
    console.log($scope.postcommentForm.customPostText);
    var length = $scope.postcommentForm.customPostText.length
    if(length >4 && length < 255)
    {
                alert("not undefined");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Bericht moet minimaal 5 karakters bevatten.");
    }
}
```

});